# How to use rails Initialization events?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Specifically, I would like to run the [before_configuration](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.1/configuring.html#initialization-events) block. But I don't know where to define it? Do I write it in an initializer?

I tried in `initializers/my_custom_config.rb`

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.before_configuration do
    puts "in initializer before config block"
  end
end
```

But it doesn't seem to actually run before the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't pass the block to `Rails.application.configure`.According to [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events) put it like this:

```
Rails.application.config.before_initialize do
  # initialization code goes here
end
```

Comment: Which file should it be in?

Comment: @Deekor Try it on `initializers/my_custom_config.rb`

Comment: @Deekor If `initializers/my_custom_config.rb` file doesn't work, try to put it on your `environment` files, like `config/environments/development.rb`